# How to get Subtotal value?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am currently trying to get the Subtotal value with Magento 1.9.1.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

    class AG_Fee_Model_Fee extends Varien_Object{



        public static function getFee(){

        $subtotal = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal());

            $feeAmt = $subtotal;

            return $feeAmt;

        }

        public static function canApply($address){

            $setFee = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/fee/active');

            if($setFee==1)

            {

                return true;

            }

        }

    }
```

I am calling the subtotal like this:
`$subtotal = Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal());`
But it's giving me no result...

Where is the problem?

I'll be so gratefull to you if you can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: unless you have set the subtotal for $this the getSubtotal() call would not return anything. The reason it doesn't error out is you have extended from Varien_Object which has magic getters.

Comment: I haven't set it. How i can make it?
Thank you so much!

Comment: The approach Marius posted should work. You might have to post more of what, when and how you are executing your code.

Answer (score 6):

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$subtotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
```

Comment: Thanks but it still not getting the value and it's displayed.

Comment: i used this but it always give wrong subtotal don't know why but when i used @TBI Infotech solution it works perfectly.  any idea why this happen

Comment: @MageLerner. I wrote this 4.5 years ago. I have no idea. Maybe something changed in the newer version. Maybe I was just simply wrong. Use what works for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
$subtotal = round($totals["subtotal"]->getValue()); //Subtotal value
```

Comment: Why @Marius answer is not getting right total do you have any idea about this

Answer (score 2):

Your information is very limited, and it's a very late reply, but others running into this, could try this:

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal())
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getData('subtotal');
```